# can you use 2 as a multiplicity in class diagrams

Tags: uml

I ask this because we were given a specific question, and that was "Q2. The United Nations wants to keep track of the bilateral (involving only two countries) trade treaties that various countries enter into." where we have to write the class diagrams in UML.
I would imagine that there would be one treaty to two countries but in every example i can find all examples show 0..* , 1..* , 1 or 1..6 (any sized random number) meaning that it should start with a 0 or 1 and nothing to show or explain if the minimum/maximum can be any other number other than 1

Comment: Please improve the readability of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**YES** you can use 2 as multiplicity, see [http://www.uml-diagrams.org/multiplicity.html](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/multiplicity.html#multiplicity) for more details, examples..

As pointed by @Blatorg some simpler or older tools or very new tools may not support the multiplicity of 2 (or 2..3 etc). Below is some list of serious tools and manuals I'm aware of and their `multiplicity 2` support status:

- **yes** - online book [www.uml-diagrams.org](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/multiplicity.html#multiplicity)
- **yes** - online book [agilemodeling.com](http://agilemodeling.com/artifacts/classDiagram.htm)
- **yes** - desktop tool [Sparx Systems Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com/products/ea/index.html)
- **yes** - desktop tool [Modeliosoft's Modelio](http://www.modeliosoft.com/en.html)
- **yes** - desktop tool [Change Vision's Astah](http://www.astah.net/)
- **no** - online tool [GenMyModel](http://www.genmymodel.com/)

Comment: Although that is true, I have encountered tools that restrict what you can enter for multiplicity to a set of predefined entries. Suffice it to say that I have not used these tools for long...

Comment: @Blatorg although you are right, in my test set 83% of tools support the multiplicity of 2. So I think OP can walk away with positive result. Average awareness that the 24bit color scale starts with 0x000000 (black) ends with 0xFFFFFF (white) with several million of other colors in the middle - should be sufficient